# How to preserve store procedure's formatting while creating it from one database to another using c# ado.net?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ado.net

I am creating store procedures from one source database to another destination database using c# console application. For that i have list of store procedures from source database. I iterate through that list and get definition of that sp by this command

```
Select definition from sys.sql_modules where object_id = OBJECT_ID ('" + item.SPName + "')"
```

and whatever defintion i get for that sp i am executing that result in destination database by

```
var idrSPCreate = cmdSPCreate.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

by this method i can successfully create store procedures in destination database. but my problem is that i am losing all formatting/indentation in destination database. How to preserve sp's formatting/indentation? is there any way or my question is invalid?

Getting sp's definition's code is below :

```
 var cmdTextSP = string.Format("Select definition from sys.sql_modules where object_id = OBJECT_ID ('" + item.SPName + "')");
 cmd.CommandText = cmdTextSP;
 var idrSP = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

and executing that definition in destination database using below code :

```
while (idrSP.Read())
{
    if (idrSP.HasRows)
    {
         var SPDefinition = idrSP.GetString(0);
         connDest.Open();
         cmdSPCreate = connDest.CreateCommand();
         cmdSPCreate.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
         cmdSPCreate.CommandText = string.Format(SPDefinition);
         var idrSPCreate = cmdSPCreate.ExecuteNonQuery();
         connDest.Close();
     }
}
```